# Retrieve two foreign keys nodejs sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, sequelize.js

I have a route and I want it to send two primary keys as foreign keys to my orderline table. I have three tables a customer, address and orderline table. an orderline has one customer and one address as foreign keys. I´m really struggling to figure it out. My route looks like this:

```
import express from "express";
import expressAsyncHandler from 'express-async-handler';
import { isAuth } from '../utlis';
import {Orderline, Address} from '../models';


const orderRouter = express.Router();

orderRouter.post(
    '/',
    isAuth,
    expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
      const customerId = req.customer.id;
      const addresss = Address.findOne({where: {CustomerId: customerId}})
      const addressId = addresss.id
      
      const createdOrder = ({
        totalPrice: req.body.totalPrice,
        itemsPrice: req.body.itemsPrice,
        taxPrice: req.body.taxPrice,
        shippingPrice: req.body.shippingPrice,
        AddressId: addressId,
        CustomerId: customerId
      });
      Orderline.create(createdOrder);
      res.status(201).send({ message: 'New Order Created', data: createdOrder});
    })
);
export default orderRouter;
```

As seen in the code I have attempted to retrieve the address that has the id of the user logged in and then gett the ID and send that as the value. I would ideally like to find the postcode,address and customerID in the address table and  Any help/guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to indicate `await` to the left from 'findOne' and `create` because they are async functions and you want to get the result in the calling code:

```js
const customerId = req.customer.id;
const address = req.address;
const postcode = req.postcode;
const addresss = await Address.findOne({
  where: {
    CustomerId: customerId,
    address: address,
    postcode: postcode
  }
})
const addressId = addresss.id
      
const createdOrder = ({
  totalPrice: req.body.totalPrice,
  itemsPrice: req.body.itemsPrice,
  taxPrice: req.body.taxPrice,
  shippingPrice: req.body.shippingPrice,
  AddressId: addressId,
  CustomerId: customerId
});
const newOrder = await Orderline.create(createdOrder);
// in case you want to send the whole orderline object along with its generated ID
res.status(201).send({ message: 'New Order Created', data: newOrder});
```

And if you don't indicate `attributes` option in `findOne` you will get all attributes of `Address`.

Comment: thank you for you response. the code you provided didn't do what I wanted it to do :/ I want to send two different id´s. One for the customer and one for the specific address they´re using incase they have registered different addresses. Ideally I would want to find the customerId and the address and post code int the "const address await" variable

Comment: But you siad you pass two ids - customer id and address id so you don't want to find out a customer id, only other address fields

Comment: Sorry, what I mean to say is, I want to find an address. I want to look inside the address table find the addresses that a customer has registered by looking at the CustomerID, postcode and address, which are column names in my Address table. I then want to retrieve id of the address found to the send to my orderline table as a foreign key(AddressId).

Comment: I added these two fields to my answer

Comment: I´m getting the error that "WHERE parameter "address" has invalid "undefined" value", does req.address etc refer to the screen or the address table? I believe what happening is the route isn't receiving the value/data of the address.

Comment: Yes, I juyst guessed that an address should be in `req.address`. It's up to you to get it properly from a request and use in the query